# Clicker game in python not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the code off a clicker below and I'm trying to solve how to show to the number of clicks on the window in tkinter. I'm new to python. If I click on the button the number of clicks remains the same. I don't know if the text doesn't updates or if the increase() function doesn't work. Please help me solve this.

```
from tkinter import *

clicks = 0
def increase(clicks):
    clicks += 1

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
label=Label(text="Clicks:")
show=Label(text=clicks)
btc = Button(text="Click me", command=increase(clicks))

label.pack()
show.pack()
btc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Along with [Using global variables in a function](//stackoverflow.com/q/423379)

Comment: And the next thing you'll be interested in will be [How to make a Tkinter label update?](//stackoverflow.com/q/28303346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the label to have a variable of a particular kind called an `IntVar()`

Then use `.set()` and `.get()` to change the variable value and get its value. When it is changed then the label is automatically.

I suggest you have a look at [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) link.

Working Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def increase():
    clicks.set(clicks.get() + 1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
label=Label(root, text="Clicks:")
clicks = IntVar()
show=Label(root, textvariable=clicks)
btc = Button(root, text="Click me", command=increase)

label.pack()
show.pack()
btc.pack()

root.mainloop()
```